# Access members of nested class

Tags: c++, nested-class

```
class A
{
        class B
        {
                int x;
        }

public:
        void printX() { std::cout << ????; }
}
```

How can I access the x variable from the A class function? I can't make it static either...

I tried everything but it either tells me I need an object in order to access it or the compiler doesn't find the function.

Comment: Unless it's some how allocated (static, or an instance of B exists), there isn't a way because it doesn't actually exist at run time (or for that matter at compile time, other than declaring it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it either tells me I need an object [...]

Think about that.  Because that's exactly what the problem is here.

If you instantiate an `A`, *you don't also get a `B`*. A nested class isn't a member variable of the enclosing class.  It's really just another way to change the namespace of a class.

So, you need an instance of `B`.  Perhaps a member of `A`?

```
class A
{
        class B
        {
        public:
                int x;
        } mB;

public:
        void printX() { std::cout << mB.x; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't ever declare an *instance* of the class B inside A. You need to do something like this:

```
    class A
    {
            class B
            {
            public:
                    int x;
            };

            B b;

    public:
            void printX() { std::cout << b.x; }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You do need an object in order to use the x variable. You could, however make it static. The problem with your example is x is not public. Placing B inside A does not make B part of A, it only changes B's scope.

From this example it kinda looks like you're after inheritance instead. This would give you the effect you're after ( access to all B's methods and variables without making an object. )

```
Class B
{
protected:
    int x;
}
Class A : B
{
    void printX() { std::cout << x; }
}
```